# Why is my text not in middle of the blocks on nav bar? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

I want the text in the center but they all seem to be sticking on top of the nav bar. 
see my image attached. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. 
edit:I am unable to attach image as I don't have 10 reputations.

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#"> Home </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Products </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">  Services </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Contact us </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">  About us </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Blog </a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you add a fiddle and show us ?

Comment: side note: background-color: **blue** not **#blue** (corrected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `line-height` same has `height` to align text of 'a' vertically to center.

set the style on `a` or `a:link, a:visited`

```
a {
   line-height: 30px;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ohd88coo/)

[image: Screenshot of centered text]

Answer (score 1):

Take padding from top padding-top:12px of a:link, a:visited in your css

and it's done

Answer (score 0):

Because of that you gave `padding:0 the text is sticking to the top`.

so i changed two thing and it works for me.

```
padding:5px 0px;
height:20px;//To make your `li height 30px`
```

Fiddle: [Text at center](http://jsfiddle.net/dj27hgz6/1/)

Comment: Kind of works. But text still doesn't show at the center. Now the nav bar has increased its width. I wanted the original width but text to be in the very center of each blocks.

Comment: @Summer :: I checked with Firebug too. Its working correctly. As padding top and bottom 5 each so 10px and height is 20px so in total 30px as of original. If you still want in middle then you can increase padding and decrease height.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want...Just add a `padding-top` to the `anchor` tag.

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top:12px;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#"> Home </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Products </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">  Services </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Contact us </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">  About us </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Blog </a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add line height to a tag 

<style>
    body {
  background-color: white;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-top:10px; in a:link, a:visited`

Here is working fiddle :[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdktkd4t/)